# How do I call a simple "Hello World" Java program in MATLAB?

Tags: java, matlab

here is my java program, how to call this in matlab?

```
package vish;

public class hello {
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
       System.out.println("Hello Java");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99993-how-do-i-call-a-simple-hello-world-java-program-in-matlab

Comment: step 5 is not working..it gives me error like this ..Undefined function or variable 'HelloWorld'. in http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99993-how-do-i-call-a-simple-hello-world-java-program-in-matlab

Comment: did you follow tutorial correctly .in your case you should use  hello not HelloWorld

Comment: yeah sorry it gives me error Undefined function or variable 'hello'

Comment: did you add class path to `classpath.txt`.example if your hello.class path is ‪`C:\Users\me\Desktop\java\hello.class` then you should add `C:\Users\me\Desktop\java` to classpath txt.do you get any error after restart matlab

Comment: my class path is D:\eclipse\simple\src\vish\hello.java , I try with both syntax ;D:\eclipse\simple\src\vish and D:\eclipse\simple\src\vish\hello.java , when I create an object of class hello...o=hello it gives me error like ...Undefined function or variable 'hello'.And there is no error after restart Matlab

Answer (score 0):

[this guide will help you](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99993-how-do-i-call-a-simple-hello-world-java-program-in-matlab)

if you get error `Undefined function or variable 'hello'`probably because of your package declaration .first try removing package declaration and try to run a single class file.

this is a video tutorial created by me .follow it.
http://youtu.be/adWtyTbQOA4